# Formular un Script correctamente en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

necesito validar las entradas de los registros de mi aplicación y todo me corre bien, solo que si se coloca un usuario con una clave Vacía el lo acepta, necesito acomodar esto... a continuación procedo a implementar el código donde valido

```
public void onClickAceptar (View view) {
    //metodo utilizado para guardar en la BD
    //1)las variables usadas para llenar la tabla usuario

    String auxn = aetidr.getText().toString();  //tomamos el nombre
    String auxp = aetpassr.getText().toString();//tomamos la clave
    String auxc = aetpasscr.getText().toString();//con este validamos la clave

    //verificamos QUE NADA QUEDE SIN LLENAR!!!

    //si la variable que acepta el nombre esta vacia nos pedira ingresar usuario
    if (auxn.isEmpty()){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ingrese un Usuario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //sino... si la clave es vacia entonces te pide que coloques una clave
    }else if (auxp == null){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ingrese una contraseña",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //si la clave de confirmacion es igual a la clave entonces guardalo en el sistema

   //-----AQUI ES EL PROBLEMA!! NO ESTOY SEGURO PERO NO DOY CON EL ------
     }else if (auxp.equals(auxc)){

        //abrimos la base de datos
        SQLite admin = new SQLite(this,"administracion", null, 1);

        //creamos variable re-escribible
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        //creamos un contenedor llamado registro
        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

        //cargamos los datos en el contenedor..
        //diciendo... "registro se cargue con variable "usuario" y el valor de auxn
        registro.put("usuario", auxn);
        //diciendo... "registro se cargue con variable "clave" y el valor de auxn
        registro.put("clave", auxp);
        //estas variables deben ser EXACTAS a la de la tabla!


        // los inserto en la base de datos diciendo:
        //variable db (creada arriba) insertara los valores EN la tabla "usuarios", null, con el contenido de "registro"

        bd.insert("usuarios", null, registro);

        //cerramos bd
        bd.close();

        // ponemos los campos a vacío para insertar el siguiente usuario
        aetidr.setText("");
        aetpasscr.setText("");
        aetpassr.setText("");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Datos del usuario cargados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: usa la opcion de `equals` de esta forma  `if (auxn.equals("")){//tu mensaje de error}`

Comment: se que esto es una pagina muy formal, pero soy MUY espontaneo asi que .. TE AMO! gracias diste con lo que era :D  GRACIAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: deja publico la respuesta y le das aceptar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usa la opcion de `equals` de esta forma

`if (auxn.equals("")){//tu mensaje de error}`

igual para no usar Toast puedes usar propiedade del `EditText`

```
aetidr.setError("Usuario Requerido");
```

Quedaria de esta forma

```
if (auxn.equals("")){
     aetidr.setError("Usuario Requerido");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

haber prueba esto

```
else if (auxp.equals("")){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ingrese una contraseña",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```

Comment: gracias, intente tu metodo y aunque es parecido al de Miguel Osorio, no me corria y luego vi que era auxn y no auxp :S pero gracias igual de verdad agradezco la atencion brindada :D  esta pagina hace que me regresen las ganas de programar :D

Comment: pero ya te quedo?

Comment: si, como dije solo cambiar la variable pero si me ayudaron gracias :D